# Escaping the dollar sign in velocity using backslash not working

Tags: java, velocity

I have the following segment to get rendered from a velocity template file.

```
xyz $$foo
```

The dollar signs need to be escaped from VTL parser. And in the template file I represented it as

```
xyz \$\$foo
```

I expect

```
xyz $$foo
```

but I get

```
xyz \$foo
```

What am I doing wrong??

Comment: tried that but it didn't work

Answer (score 47, accepted):

One of the way is to use a fixed string variable i.e, setting a variable for the $ sign and then using it.

```
#set ( $d = "$")
xyz ${d}${d}foo
```

It gives the expected output

```
xyz $$foo
```

Answer (score 3):

You might also want to check out the [EscapeTool](http://velocity.apache.org/tools/devel/generic/EscapeTool.html) in velocity.

Once you have included it in context (e.g. under the name "esc"), you can use ${esc.d} to get the dollar sign. The method is you mentioned is easier for this particular case though.

I thought it was worth mentioning because it provides several other convenient methods to escape strings appropriate, if your templates are generating Java/javascript/html etc.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Unparsed Content](https://velocity.apache.org/engine/2.3/vtl-reference.html#unparsed-content):

```
#[[xyz $$foo]]#
```

Answer (score -3):

It might also be helpful to use Velocity's [NumberTool](http://velocity.apache.org/tools/devel/javadoc/org/apache/velocity/tools/generic/NumberTool.html).

It has a built in currency formatter:

```
$myNumber                   -> 13.55
$number.format($myNumber)   -> 13.6
$number.currency($myNumber) -> $13.55
$number.integer($myNumber)  -> 13
```

Comment: The OP asks about escaping the dollar symbol that has meaning of printing a variable with the name after it.